# "Using $this when not in object context in" - PHP OO (MVC)

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

I saw many questions about my problem, but, unfortunately, without fix.

So, my syntax's error is:

> Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in ... on line
>   18.

My line 18:

> ```
>       echo $this->login;
> ```

My full code:

```
<?php

class LoginModel extends LoginController {

    private $_db;
    public $login;
    public $pass;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->_db = Db::getInstance();
        $this->login = addslashes(trim($_GET['tgo-root-user']));
        $this->pass = addslashes(trim(md5($_GET['tgo-root-password'].SALT)));

    }

    public function auth() {
        echo $this->login;
        /*$pdo = $this->_db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `tgo_users` WHERE ((:login = `user_login`) OR (:login = `user_email`)) AND (:user_pw = `user_pw`) " );
        $pdo->bindParam( ":login", $this->login, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $pdo->bindParam( ":user_pw", $this->pass, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $pdo->execute();

        if( $pdo->rowCount() == 1 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }*/

    }


}
```

My call:

```
<?php

class LoginController {

    public static $status;

    public function authenticate() {

        $model = new LoginModel();
        $this->status = $model->auth();

        LoginView::emitAuthResponse();

    }


}
```

So I ask: what's wrong? Damn.. I'm loosing to much time with this problem and I don't know what's wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You propably call it like

```
LoginModel::auth();
```

`auth()` is not `static`, thus you need an object of `LoginModel` to call it.

```
$x = new LoginModel;
$x->auth();
```

Comment: Hello, KingCrunch. Thank you for your answer - but I've edited the main post with the call. Look that.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge: Are you sure you're not calling it from somewhere else too or forgetting to upload a changed file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "$this", then you can't have $status be static. I think it is screwing up here...

```
$this->status = $model->auth();
```

Comment: Oh, dude, unfortunately: nothing - again. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You removed the static? That should have done it

Answer (score 1):

Use [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) to look at the call stack and figure out where you're calling `LoginModel::auth()` statically.

Comment: +1 Learned a handy new debugging function.